# Get string from HTML class object

Tags: html, ios, uitableview

Basically what I'm trying to do is get the value of a html class.

The class in question is part of a forum, and when you get messages, notifications etc, it gives a number count. I want to get that count and load it into a table view.

So far I have established the badged cell accessory view like so:

```
            MLPAccessoryBadge *accessoryBadge = [MLPAccessoryBadge new];
            [accessoryBadge setText:@"test"];

            [cell setAccessoryView:accessoryBadge];
            UIView *number = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
            number.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.176 green:0.176 blue:0.176 alpha:1];
            cell.backgroundView = number;
```

No I need to figure out how to pass the below code to the setText part above.

```
<span class="ipsHasNotifications">%@</span>
```

What would be the best practice to do this?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: what kind of object contains the HTML that you can parse?  A `NSURLResponse` object or something else?

Comment: If you're talking about the whole part of the HTML part it is: <div id="toggle_messenger"><a href="https://siteit.com/index.php?app=members&amp;module=messaging" title="Messenger"><span class="ipsHasNotifications">1</span><i class="ii icon-envelope ii-bar"></i></a></div> The 1 indicates 1 notification. Obviously, that will change.